# What area of statistics deals with such kind of problems?

Tags: statistics, reference-request

Consider $2$ samples from the starting normal distribution with parameters $\mu=0, \sigma = 1$ with size $N$. Find the variance of the random variable $\xi$ equal to average sum of $1$st sample - average sum of $2$nd sample.

My course of mathematical statistics did not include topics related to such problems, so can you point out what area of statistics deals with such kind of problems?

Comment: @probablyme  My statistics textbook doesn't have problems with sampling, and my studies was long time ago, so I tried nothing, I look for book/paper which contains such problems, but have no idea how formulate query for search. By `mean of 1st/2nd sample` I mean average (sum of N / N). About `independent` it is not defined in task, so I can not assume that for this samples.

Comment: @probablyme So I am not interesting in solution of this task by itself, but in paper/book where such task described/solved.

Comment: @probablyme Any examples of such book, what you have on your book shelf? I pick my book for mathematical statistic and it not contains similar problems. But my native language is not English, I heard that USA/GB books are more practical then in my country. So can you give name of such textbook?

Comment: Sorry, I have no recommendation. I did not learn probability from a textbook, and my mathematical statistics book was very bad. I'm sure someone will have a good suggestion.

Comment: In general, try searching the site first. You're not the first person [to ask this](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=[statistics]%20[reference-request]%20book%20recommendation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you state isn't fundamentally a problem in
sampling, but based on principles of elementary probability.
So I wonder if it may be in the books you have, but that the
connections are not immediately obvious to you.

As a generalization of your problem consider one sample of
size $n$ from $N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ and an independent sample of
size $m$ from $N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2).$ Then the difference
in sample means is distributed as follows:
$$\bar X_1 - \bar X_2 \sim N\left(\mu_1 - \mu_2, 
\frac{\sigma_1^2}{n} + \frac{\sigma_2^2}{m}\right).$$
So in your particular case, 
$\bar X_1 - \bar X_2 \sim N(0,\, 2/N)$.
Notice that the second parameter of the normal distribution in my
notation is the $variance$ in all cases, not the standard deviation.

There are two issues here. First, sums and differences of independent  normal
random variables are normal. This theorem can be proved using moment
generating functions. but is often just stated as a fact in
very elementary texts. Second, you need to know some fundamental
facts about means and variances of sums and differences of random
variables:

For any two random variables $X$ and $Y$,

$$E(aX \pm bY) = aE(X) \pm bE(Y).$$

For two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$,

$$Var(aX \pm bY) = a^2Var(X) + b^2Var(Y).$$

In the second equation notice that the variances are always added.
In your particular problem $a = b = 1.$
These can be used to prove that for a random sample $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ from a population with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2,$ we have
$E(\bar X) = \mu$ and $Var(\bar X) = \sigma^2/n.$

You should be able to find all  of the displayed relationships above in many advanced undergraduate texts on probability
theory or mathematical statistics. One such book, now available
in paperback for a relatively reasonable price, is Bain and Englehardt:
*Intro. to Probability and Mathematical Statistics,* (1992, 1978).
The topics above are in Chapters 4 and 5. I would not want to claim it is the very best choice for you, but I have
taught out of it several times. I have found it to be generally clearly written,
and it contains some applied examples.